# Leveling Stack Block

Tags: wall

I'm building a stack block wall using interlocking block. The base level went well - things are level and all the block are stable. But as I layer on additional levels, minor inconsistencies in the blocks are making them imbalanced. Some of them wobble up to a couple millimeters.

I've tried adding small amounts of sand to level the intermediate blocks. They just seems to make the problem worse the higher I go. I'm building the wall to be 7 blocks high (1st block and a half set into the ground). The problem really shows at about the 4th block, but even the second row wobbles a bit.

Will this impact the stability of the finished wall?

How do I fix it? Redo the whole thing?

Additional Information:

I'm repairing an existing wall. The wall is 3 feet high. I've dug out the wooden steps and removed the block immediately next to the steps to put in new stairs. The existing wall appears to have been built on a mix of coarse gravel and sand. Behind the wall is landscape fabric and behind that is garden bed soil (purchased specifically for growing garden vegetables).

Comment: Can you please include the following information in your original question? Did you prepare any type of foundation - that is - concrete, rock, sand or similar. What will be the final height above ground level? What is the nature of the ground behind the wall - that is - above the back fill?